# How to set Incoming email Active Directory container for new distribution groups using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2016

In the Central Administration of SharePoint 2016, 'Incoming E-Mail Settings' page, I need to set the property for the field 'Active Directory container where new distribution groups and contacts will be created'.

I cannot find using PowerShell the actual property to set the AD container.

Anybody know how I can set it?

Thanks.

```
        #Configure SP incoming mail settings
        $svcinstance = Get-SPServiceInstance | ? { $_.TypeName -eq 'Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Incoming E-Mail' }  
        $incomingMail = $svcinstance.Service  

        if ($incomingMail -ne $null) {  
            #Enable sites on this server to receive e-mail  
            $incomingMail.Enabled = $true  

            #Automatic Settings mode  
            $incomingMail.UseAutomaticSettings = $false  

            #Use the SharePoint Directory Management Service to create distribution groups  
            $incomingMail.UseDirectoryManagementService = $true

            #Accept messages from authenticated users only  
            $incomingMail.DLsRequireAuthenticatedSenders = $true  

            #Allow creation of distribution groups from SharePoint sites  
            $incomingMail.DistributionGroupsEnabled = $true  

            #SMTP mail server for incoming mail  
            $incomingMail.ServerAddress = $smtpServerDomainName  

            #E-mail server display address  
            $incomingMail.ServerDisplayAddress = $emailDisplayAddress  

            #E-mail drop folder  
            $incomingMail.DropFolder = $emailDropFolder 

            $incomingMail.Update();  
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Found out how to achieve this:

```
#Active Directory container where new distribution groups and contacts will be created    
$webApp = Get-SPWebApplication -IncludeCentralAdministration | Where {$_.DisplayName -eq "SharePoint Central Administration v4"}
$site = $webApp.Sites[0]
$web = $site.RootWeb

if($web.AllProperties['EmailWebService_ADContainer']){
    $web.AllProperties.Remove('EmailWebService_ADContainer');   
    $web.Properties['EmailWebService_ADContainer'] = $null;
    $web.Update();
    $web.Properties.Update();
}

$web.AllProperties.Add('EmailWebService_ADContainer',$activeDirectoryOU) 
$web.Update() 
$web.Dispose();
$site.Dispose();
```

Reference: https://www.reddit.com/r/sharepoint/comments/cr85mn/how_to_set_incoming_email_active_directory_for/